# Finding a recurrence relation for the Josephus problem if we're looking at the person before the person who lives

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Consider the Josephus problem. Let $L(n)$ be the number of the next to
>   last person left standing. Find $L(12)$ and $L(13)$. Derive a recurrence
>   for $L(n)$.

I know that the Josephus problem is solved with the recurrence relation $f(2j) = 2(f(j)) - 1$.

But if the problem, as seen above, it switched to the person before the last person standing, how would I go about solving it? This question is really confusing me.

Comment: I think this is in Chapter 1 of *Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth, Graham, & Patashnik.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: This is Problem $1.15$ of Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*. $L(1)$ is undefined, but otherwise $L$ satisfies the same recurrence as the Josephus function $f$:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&L(2)=2\\
&L(3)=1\\
&L(2n)=2L(n)-1&&\text{if }n\ge 2\\
&L(2n+1)=2L(n)+1&&\text{if }n\ge 2\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

Break the integers into blocks of the form

$$\left[2^m+2^{m-1},2^{m+1}+2^m\right)\cap\Bbb Z\;:$$

$[11_{\text{two}},110_{\text{two}})$, $[110_{\text{two}},1100_{\text{two}})$, and so on. Each $n\ge 3$ can then be written in the form $$n=2^m+2^{m-1}+k\;,$$ where $$0\le k<2^{m+1}+2^m-\left(2^m+2^{m-1}\right)=2^m+2^{m-1}\;.$$

Now show that when $n$ is written in this fashion, $L(n)$ is a simple function of $k$.